# Customized auto-incremented value in a column in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is for SQL Server 2016.

Can we have auto-incremented alphanumeric value set for column?

For eg:

[image]

Here value for column Channel is auto-incremented.

Appreciate your suggestion very much.

Comment: Don't mess with the auto-increment! You can generate that column on-the-fly in your select statement. No need to store it in the table

Comment: Have you already stored values for the "Channel" column in the database? If so how did you do that?

Also what version of SQL are you running? If it's a newer version you could utilise  CONCAT() to join the string 'JOSH' to the number, although you'll need to convert the number to a VARCHAR for the concat to work.

Comment: @TomCamish you can concatenate strings in all versions

Comment: Why `JOSH`? What is this prefix supposed to mean? `Smart` keys are a terrible choice for primary keys, and a problem in any case.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's not available in SQL 2003 which unfortunately some companies still use with legacy apps.

Comment: @TomCamish there's no such SQL Server version. There were 2000 and 2005. Concatenating strings is available in *all* versions using `+` as long as both sides are (or can be implicitly cast) to strings

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My previous comment was supposed to say 2008, not 2003. Indeed using + works, however I specifically mentioned the CONCAT() function, which is cleaner, which wasn't introduced until SQL 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution is to use

- an `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value
- a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Channels
(
     ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
     ChannelID AS 'JOSH' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(3)), 3) PERSISTED,
     .... your other columns here....
)
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `Channels` without specifying values for `ID` or `ChannelID`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblCompany(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will **automatically and safely** increase your `ID` value, and `ChannelID` will contain values like `JOSH001`, `JOSH002`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.

Or as @JuergenD already mentioned in a comment: don't store the `ChannelID` in the table at all - just compute it, based on the `ID`, when needed in a `SELECT` (or in a view)

Comment: @SophiaD'souza: hmm.... you're on SQL Server 2016, I'm on 2017 - and it works just fine for me. Not clear if there's another problem in your `CREATE TABLE` script then .... can you post the whole `CREATE TABLE` script you're trying??

Comment: ah! it is working perfectly..... problem was with my DDL